# How do I plot a function that varies with the domain using matlibplot

Tags: arrays, function, numpy

I want the function merge_complexity(n) to return 1 for n == 1 and n*log(n) otherwise. Instead I get an error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
def wrong_but_working_func(n):
    return n*np.log(n)
```

From my understanding of the error the argument n is the entire array but I know defining a function that doesn't vary over the domain treats n as the current value of the array. e.g the above function would work but ofcourse isn't what I want. Below is the code I tried and the function I want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def merge_complexity(n):
    if (n==1):
        return 1
    else:
    return n*np.log(n)

n = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
plt.plot(n, [1,merge_complexity(n)],'g')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Time complexity of merge sort w/ input size n')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Matlab is not matplotlib and I don't see any connection to dns. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: there isnt a matplotlib tag its related

Comment: I don't know much about python, being a Matlab person, but I would say the error is telling you that you are comparing an array to a scalar.

Comment: Another problem you are likely to encounter is that log(0) is undefined.

Comment: Not finding the appropriate tags is no reason to use any tag. There is a tag for matplotlib and tagging the used programming language as well is typically a good idea. Removed the unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining "Python style" with "numpy style" (even though technically, `numpy` is run over Python) in a way which, not only isn't exactly working for you, but, moreover, can be made more sensible.

When using `numpy`, you should try to work in a [vectorized manner](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html) - it's what gives the speed that Python lacks. Instead of `merge_complexity`, write something like:

```
y = np.where(n == 0, 1, n * np.log(n))
```

[`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the vectorized "if", and `n * np.log(n)` is vectorized too.

You can just plot `y` vs. `n` now.